# How to allow user to install only if a given registry key doesn't have a certain value?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project, jscript, post-build

One of the conditions for running my installer is that a value in the registry should be different from "1", otherwise it would display an error message and quit.

This can't be done through custom actions since even the `OnBeforeInstall` event happens after install, so the user could terminate the setup before the rollback.

If I was using WiX it would be simples as

```
<Condition Message="This application cannot be installed with SOMESOFTWARE v1. Setup now will exit.">
    <![CDATA[SOMESOFTWAREVERSION <> "#1"]]>
</Condition>

<Property Id="SOMESOFTWAREVERSION">
    <RegistrySearch Id="SomeSoftwareVersion"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Some Manufacturer\SomeSoftware"
                    Name="SomeSoftwareVersion"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

How can I do the same without WiX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a post build JScript for your MSI file. Or you can do it manually in Orca.

```
var installer = WScript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
var filespec = WScript.Arguments(0);
var msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1;
var database = installer.OpenDatabase(filespec, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);

Execute("INSERT INTO `AppSearch` (`Property`, `Signature_`) VALUES ('SOMESOFTWAREVERSION', 'SomeSoftwareVersion')");
Execute("INSERT INTO `RegLocator` (`Signature_`, `Root`, `Key`, `Name`, `Type`) VALUES ('SomeSoftwareVersion', 2, 'SOFTWARE\\Some Manufacturer\\SomeSoftware', 'SomeSoftwareVersion', 2)");
Execute("INSERT INTO `LaunchCondition` (`Condition`, `Description`) VALUES ('SOMESOFTWAREVERSION <> \"#1\"', 'This application cannot be installed with SOMESOFTWARE v1. Setup now will exit.')");

function Execute(sql) {
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();
}
```

It will check Wow6432Node on 64-bit Windows just as WiX does